# Using array_merge to initialize static class variable in derived class based on parent class

Tags: php, oop

**UPDATE**: Solved! See below for what I ended up doing. Thanks everyone, I love SO!

---

This is a bit technical question, sorry for that I am still learning PHP OOP...

Why am I allowed to do this:

```
<ul>    
<?php 
   class Base {
      public static $array = array(
         'test1' => 'Hello',
      );
   }

   class Derived extends Base {
      public static $array = array(
         'test2' => 'World!'
      );
   }

   foreach (Derived::$array as $key => $value) { 
?>      
   <li><?= $key ?> = <?= $value ?></li>
<?php 
    } 
?>
</ul>
```

Which outputs:

```
<ul>
   <li>test2 = World!</li>
</ul>
```

But not this (notice the call to array_merge):

```
<ul>    
<?php 
   class Base {
      public static $array = array(
         'test1' => 'Hello',
      );
   }

   class Derived extends Base {
      public static $array = array_merge(parent::$array, array(
         'test2' => 'World!'
      ));
   }

   foreach (Derived::$array as $key => $value) { 
?>      
   <li><?= $key ?> = <?= $value ?></li>
<?php 
    } 
?>
</ul>
```

Which would output (if it was allowed):

```
<ul>
   <li>test1 = Hello</li>
   <li>test2 = World!</li>
</ul>
```

The second example gives me a syntax error:

> unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

Before you ask why I want this... I am building an object hierarchy of objects that are persisted to the database and I would like to have an array on the class with the default values for all the fields. I can build it by just repeating the fields from the base class in the derived class, but that seems redundant (DRY principle).

Maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way, so if you have a much better idea to solve the same problem I would thank you very much and accept it as answer.

---

**UPDATE**: Thanks to **doydoy44** I found a satisfactory solution:

I am using a static function on the base class that returns the merged array. It uses a kind of reflection to recursively call itself all the way up the hierarchy tree until all arrays have been merged:

```
<?php 
   class Base {
      protected static $array = array(
         'test1' => 'Hello',
      );

      public static function getArray() {
         $thisClass = get_called_class();
         $parentClass = get_parent_class($thisClass);
         $exists = method_exists($parentClass, __FUNCTION__); 
         return $exists ? 
            array_merge($parentClass::getArray(), $thisClass::$array) : 
            $thisClass::$array;
      }
   }

   class Derived extends Base {
      protected static $array = array(
         'test2' => 'World!'
   );
}
?>

<ul>    
<?php
   foreach (Base::getArray() as $key => $value) { 
?>      
   <li><?= $key ?> = <?= $value ?></li>
<?php 
   } 
?>
</ul>

<ul>    
<?php
   foreach (Derived::getArray() as $key => $value) { 
?>      
   <li><?= $key ?> = <?= $value ?></li>
<?php 
   } 
?>
</ul>
```

Which outputs:

```
<ul>
   <li>test1 = Hello</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>test1 = Hello</li>
   <li>test2 = World!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You cannot initialize a class property with a non-constant expression.

Comment: just a small sidenote: it would be better practice to try to isolate html, separate php and html... never mix them in the output. my hair stands on end anytime I see these mixtures ;) this can be achieved by working with templates for example.

Comment: I am separating them, just mixing them here to create a minimal example. This way you can paste the code snippet in one file and test it... So don't worry I got you covered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
class Base {
  public static $array = array(
     'test1' => 'Hello',
  );
}

class Derived extends Base {
  public static $array = array(
     'test2' => 'Hello',
  );

  static function getArray(){
    return array_merge(self::$array, parent::$array);
  }
}
```

and call

```
Derived::getArray();
```

Comment: I ended up doing something slightly different. I will update my answer. However, you led me on the right path, so accepted your answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** do an assignment of a function return value to a variable of your class outside the constructor.

Replace

```
 class Derived extends Base {
      public static $array = array_merge(parent::$array, array(
         'test2' => 'World!'
      ));
   }
```

with

```
class Derived extends Base {

    public static $array;
    function __construct()
    {
        self::$array=array_merge(parent::$array, array(
            'test2' => 'World!'
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: he will need to instantiate an object of `Derived` to use this. you need to mention that as well

Comment: This actually still breaks my example, but in a different way. I get: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and no output. Note that I am not making any instances of `Derived` and hence the constructor is never called. Is there something like a 'static constructor' / 'class initialization block'? E.g. in Java we can add a code block to a class like this: `static { /* static code to initialize class goes here */ }`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, as it defeats the purpose of static properties.